# std::atomic<unsiged long long>: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    atomic<unsigned long long> testull {0};
    testull++;
    cout << testull << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
g++48 --std=c++11 atomictest.cpp "-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc48"
```

But `g++48` failed with the following message:

```
/var/tmp//ccTBLlRL.o: In function `std::__atomic_base<unsigned long long>::fetch_add(unsigned long long, std::memory_order)':
atomictest.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__atomic_baseIyE9fetch_addEySt12memory_order[_ZNSt13__atomic_baseIyE9fetch_addEySt12memory_order]+0x2e): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/var/tmp//ccTBLlRL.o: In function `std::__atomic_base<unsigned long long>::load(std::memory_order) const':
atomictest.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt13__atomic_baseIyE4loadESt12memory_order[_ZNKSt13__atomic_baseIyE4loadESt12memory_order]+0x2a): undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I change the `atomic<unsigned long long>` to `atomic<unsigned long>`, then it compiles without problem. Any idea why? I'm using `g++48` in `FreeBSD 9.0`

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system? How big (`sizeof`) is `unsigned long long` vs. `unsigned long`? What architecture?

Comment: I'm on a 32-bit system. The `unsigned long long` is 8 bytes, `unsigned long` is 4, just as normally expected.

Comment: What architecture? It seems that the architecture simply does not support 64 bit atomic operations...

Comment: Unfortunately, it's `i386` (`uname -a` said so). Is there any workarounds? Only `x64` supports 64-bit atomic operations?

Comment: I'm sure your CPU is more recent than i386. Tell it to your compiler, `-march=i686` could be enough.

Comment: You might try to play with `-march=i686` or `-mcpu=` or similar options to exclude compatibility with too-old CPUs that don't have the necessary instructions. (ah, yes, what Marc just said :)

Comment: `-latomic` could also help...

Comment: @MarcGlisse @DanielFrey `-march=i686` work like a charm! +1 for both of you

Comment: @MarcGlisse with `-latomic`, it compiles, but crashed at run time.

Comment: It shouldn't crash, please complain to freebsd.